Why does my Matrix multiplication program (in CUDA) work for integers 1 <= K <= 256 and when K = 512, but not when 256 < K < 512?
In the implementation below (in CUDA), I have a matrix multiplier, using the classic method of taking the dot product of matrix A's rows and matrix B_T's (already transposed) columns, where the result is placed in the ith row and jth column of Matrix C.
Matrix A dimensions (rows, columns) are (M, K), Matrix B dimensions are (K, N), and
Kpowered == uproundToPowerofTwo(K)
__global__
void gpu_matrix_multiply_RbyC(int M, int N, int Kpowered, int K, double *A, double *B_T, double* C) {
    int tidx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ double local_vector[512];
    // int K = blockDim.x;                                                                                                                                                                                    
    assert(K <= Kpowered);
    assert(K <= 512);
    // int M passed as arg                                                                                                                                                                                    

    int k = threadIdx.x;
    assert(0 <= k);
    assert(     k <= Kpowered);
    int n = blockIdx.x % N;
    assert(0 <= n);
    assert(     n <= N);
    int m = blockIdx.x / N;
    assert(0 <= m);
    assert(     m <= M);

    __syncthreads();
    if (tidx < Kpowered * N * M && k < K) {
      local_vector[k] = A[m * K + k] * B_T[n * K + k];                                             
    }

    __syncthreads();
    while (Kpowered > 1) {
      Kpowered /= 2;
      assert(Kpowered >= 1);
      auto right_idx = k + Kpowered;
      if (k < Kpowered) {
          __syncthreads();
          local_vector[k] += local_vector[right_idx];
      }
    }

    //  __syncthreads(); NOTE: if left uncommented, running the program does not stop                                                                                                                                                                           
    if (k == 0) {
      C[m * N + n] += local_vector[0];
    }
    // __syncthreads();  NOTE: if left uncommented, running the program does not stop                                                                                                                                                                               
}


int uproundToPowerOfTwo(int k) {
    assert(k > 0);
    auto n = k - 1;
    int count = 0;

    for (; n > 0; n /= 2) {
      count++;
    }
    n = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      n *= 2;
    }
    assert(n >= k);
    assert(n / 2 < k);
    return n;
}

When I test this with Matrix A of size (100, K), Matrix B of size (K, 103), it works as intended for integers 1 <= K <= 256. It also works when K = 512. But from 256 < K < 512, it does not work as intended. I fail to see why this is the case though.

I think the error comes from the sum where right_idx can exceed K. local_vector is not fully initialized: it contains random values after index K. For some reason, on your GPU, those values are zeroes until index 256, but not after.
Here is a fix to avoid using those values:
    while (Kpowered > 1) {
      Kpowered /= 2;
      assert(Kpowered >= 1);
      auto right_idx = k + Kpowered;
      if (k < Kpowered && right_idx < K) {
          __syncthreads();
          local_vector[k] += local_vector[right_idx];
      }
    }

